# Data Intensive process in EC2 - any tips?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oracle11g, etl

We are trying to run an ETL process in an **High I/O Instance** on Amazon EC2.  The same process locally on a very well equipped laptop (with a SSD) take about 1/6th the time.  This process is basically transforming data (30 million rows or so) from flat tables to a 3rd normal form schema in the same Oracle instance.

Any ideas on what might be slowing us down?

Comment: Are you using instance storage? or are you reading/writing from an EBS volume?

Comment: EBS is not being used as part of this process per se, rather we have an instance in EC2 that is using Amazon RDS to host Oracle (which may be on RBS, but it I'm not sure of the details there).

Comment: A high io instance has ssd, but are only available via instance storage. RDS does use EBS and will likely be slower if you are directly loading into RDS as your output.

Comment: So then is it safe to assume that we aren't getting the benefit of the high io instance for this operation if we are reading / writing to RDS?  Thanks so much for your response.

Comment: Yes, I don't have insight into how your etl process is written, but it sounds like it doesn't really take advantage of the disks of the high i/o instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or another option is to simply move off of AWS and rent beefy boxes (raw hardware) with SSDs in something like Rackspace.

We have moved most of our ETL processes off of AWS/EMR. We host most of it on Rackspace and getting a lot more CPU/Storage/Performance for the money. Don't get me wrong AWS is awesome but there comes a point where it's not cost effective.  On top of that you never know how they are really managing/virtualizing the hardware that applies to your specific application.

My two cents.